# Why does a network interface lose its IP address when moved to a different network namespace?

Tags: iproute, network-namespaces

Suppose I use [ip-link(8)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man8/ip.8.html) to create an interface, `test-macvlan`, and assign it the address `10.11.12.13`:

```
# ip link add link eno1 name test-macvlan type macvlan
# ip address add 10.11.12.13 dev test-macvlan
# ip address show test-macvlan
10: test-macvlan@eno1: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST> mtu 1500 ...
    link/ether d2:f7:32:3f:c9:4a brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 10.11.12.13/32 scope global test-macvlan
```

Then, I use [ip-netns(8)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man8/ip-netns.8.html) to create a network namespace, `test-netns`, and use [ip-link(8)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man8/ip.8.html) to assign the `test-macvlan` interface to the new namespace:

```
# ip netns add test-netns
# ip link set test-macvlan netns test-netns
# ip netns exec test-netns ip address show test-macvlan
10: test-macvlan@if2: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST> mtu 1500 ...
    link/ether d2:f7:32:3f:c9:4a brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff link-netns root
```

The interface no longer has an IP address. The same thing happens with a `vlan` interface, and is presumably why the [WireGuard tutorial on Routing and Network Namespace Integration](https://www.wireguard.com/netns/) requires you to assign the `wireguard` device an IP address *after* changing its network namespace.

Why does this happen? It means that [systemd-networkd needs new code to support creating virtual network devices in a network namespace](https://github.com/systemd/systemd/pull/14915/files). If the network interface's configuration were portable across network namespaces, wouldn't that simplify things by avoiding the need for containers to run their own network managers?

Comment: It also happens without systemd. Guess: the easiest way to guarantee that the configuration of an existing IF can not mess up whatever is inside a new network NS is to completely reset this configuration (you'll notice the IF is also down, if it was up before).

Comment: Ugh this issue is kicking my ass today. I dunno what it is about networking that makes default semantics always asinine. I guess preserving interface config would make our lives way too easy.

Comment: @Navin this same thing was disturbing me last week. I ended up creating a bash script that moves an interface to a netns, copies all routes, then returns it back to their origin when finished. Here's the script if you want to use it/take a look: https://github.com/kriansa/dotfiles/blob/main/modules/unix/bin/iftun